# How to make sql hive when i have input this?

Tags: sql, hive, sum

input:

```
|   a.user_id    | a_stream_length  | b_stream_length  | subtract_inactive  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      a         | 11               | 1686             | 22                 |
|      a         | 1686             | 328              | 12                 |
|      a         | 328              | 732              | 22                 |
|      a         | 732              | 11               | 1699               |
|      a         | 11               | 2123             | 18                 |
|      a         | 2123             | 160              | 2                  |
|      a         | 160              | 1358             | 0                  |
|      a         | 1358             | 129              | 1                  |
|      a         | 129              | 4042             | 109334             |
```

output:

```
|      a         | (1686+11+328+732)   (if subtract_inactive < 1000) |
|      a         | 732(a_stream_length) if subtract_inactive > 1000) |
```

Comment: The logic is not clear at all.  Where does "a" come from?  What about the 9 values in the table that are not mentioned in the results?

Comment: Hi apomene: it is meaning:
- if value of field subtract_inactive row1, row2, row3 < 1000 then result = 11 + 1686 + 328 + 732.
- else if value of field subtract_inactive row4 = 1699 > 1000 then result = 732(is field a_stream_length)
==> same: due to row5, row5, row7,row8 have field subtract_inactive < 1000 then result = 11+2123+160+1358+129.
- else due to row9 have field subtract_inactive = 109334 > 1000 => result = 129.
please, help me! Thanks so much!